# Smarty foreach including if

Tags: if-statement, foreach, smarty

I've got a foreach loop running on my site to display images. There are some images I do not wish to display however so I added an if statement to exclude these images. The problem though is that using the if statement within the loop means that I can't use $smarty.foreach.thumbnails.last to work out which image is last as it could be one of the hidden ones.

How would I go about filtering these images and still being able to use $smarty.foreach.thumbnails.last?

Here is my code as it stands:

```html
{foreach from=$images item=image name=thumbnails}
  {if $image.legend != "colorschemes"}
    {assign var=imageIds value="`$product->id`-`$image.id_image`"}                                                                                  
    <li data-imgtype="{$image.legend}" class="items{if $j == 1} main-pos{elseif $j == 2} right-pos{elseif $smarty.foreach.thumbnails.last} left-pos{else} back-pos{/if}" id="{$j}">
                                                
      <img src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'tm_large_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"  alt="Owl Image" style="width:100%; margin-top:-200px;" />
                                                
    </li>
    {$j = $j + 1}
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to filter the array in the back end before sending it to the template.  This could potentially have better performance as the client won't be loading unnecessary images. The filtering could be done in php or sql.

Comment: Unfortunately I still need the images to be used else where on the page so I can't exclude them entirely like that. I just need to hide them from this gallery. Unfortunately though, this gallery needs a specific class on the last item in it in order for it to work correctly.

Comment: @cyanoxide If you're using these images elsewhere, is it before the forloop in your question or after? If it's earlier in the code, you might include the {if $image.legend != "colorschemes"} in the first forloop as well to find out which iteration is the last one that fits your if condition and save it as a variable. Then in your second forloop use {if $j == $newVariable} to find out which iteration is last to fit your condition.